# Core Data fetching... Why doesn't Managed Object get fetched using context B after inserting it in context A and saving context A?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I am not sure what I'm missing here so I'll try to explain a problem I'm having.

I have two nsmanagedobjectcontexts. I will call them A and B.

1. I insert a new entity E in A
2. I save A
3. from B I try to fetch all the E entities found in store with a simple fetchRequest
4. When executing the NSFetchRequest to get all E entities from B I cannot get the one I inserted in A even though A was saved.
5. I can get E if I execute the NSFetchRequest against A.

I thought that once I save a context the ManagedObject in that context would get saved to the persistent store (I only have one persistent store setup). So then I thought that I could get the managed object E from what ever context I wanted since any NSFetchedRequest fetches from the persistent store into the context I'm executing it on.

What am I missing here? Why can't I get E from any context I want after saving context A in which E was inserted in in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to merge the changes from context A in to context B. or instantiate context B after the save of context A.

Take a look at the documentation for mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification on NSManagedObjectContext.

Comment: I see. That fixed the problem. So the main question about all this is: If saving a context makes it so the changes in that context are saved in the actual persistent store... why doesn't any other context see those changes when fetching from any different context? Am I wrong in saying that saving a context persists the changes on disk? if I am not wrong on that why can't any other context see those persisted changes during a fetch? I thought any context looks at the persistent store all the time... Thanks

Comment: The NSManagedObjectContext is an in memory representation of the store, as data is loaded in to the context is effectively cached in memory, and therefore stale if you save from a separate context. The changes are written to disk with each call to -save:, however they won't be visible in contexts which have already loaded objects from disk until they are merged in, or you call -reset on the context.

Comment: Great. That was my misunderstanding then. Makes sense now why registering for the notification fixed the problem. Thanks